# MongoDB aggregate query with JAVA driver

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to execute a query on my database using mongo java driver but am facing some problem.
I have executed this query from the mongo shell and it seems to work fine.

```
 db.userData.aggregate([ { $group: {"_id": "$username"}},{$group:{"_id":"userCount","counter":{$sum:1}}}])
```

This returns to me the total number of unique users in my databse.

Result is

> { "_id" : "userCount", "counter" : 5 }

I want to try the same in JAVA. I can do aggregate queries with 1 $group like the following (returns unique users with number of documents in the database for that particular user).

```
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("userData").aggregate(asList(
    new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$username").append("count", new Document("$sum", 1)))));
```

But i do not know what to do if my query uses $group twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("userData").aggregate(asList(
    new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$username").append("count", new Document("$sum", 1))),
    new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$username").append("count", new Document("$sum", 1)))));
```

This somehow returns the correct answer but it is confusing to me how it is working. Can somebody explain a bit.